# Prevent browsers from re-render CSS3 columns

Tags: css, multiple-columns

I'm using CSS3 to arrange articles ("cards") into columns. This is what I have now https://i.stack.imgur.com/REZYX.jpg

For each "card" there's a list of action buttons (those with icons). Some of them (for example the maginifier) populate content into the card. That's when a problem happens: the card gets longer, and the browser decides to re-render the columns, causing the cards to be re-arranged.  For example, a card at the bottom of the first column, once gets longer can be moved to the top of the second column. As a result, it can disappear from the current viewport and confuse the user.

Is there a way to prevent this? Thanks in advance.